# IE7 dynamic HTML rendering with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, user-interface

I'm trying to render a page dynamically with jQuery. Basically, on the page loading, I have a bunch of JSON data and I'm creating the content of the page based on that.

This is working for almost every browsers except for IE9 with IE7 standards view.

Since it's a website with a lot of different users I would like to make sure this is working for that version too. Do you know if there are any "tweaks" I can do to improve the compatibility with IE7 and dynamically rendering using jQuery?

Thanks.

NB

Comment: Are you sure it's not rendering but hidden? You might find that there's a collapsing container issue in IE7 mode on IE9. Try console.log()ing the steps for rendering and then checking the elements rendered exist after your code is completed.  If it does, then it's probably an IE7 display issue rather than rendering issue.

Comment: Be sure to include relevant code when you ask a question. Without it, this question will likely be closed.

Comment: What error message do you get in the console of IE? There's no reason it shouldn't work. Can you post your code too?

Comment: Hi MyStream, you're right. The Javascript is adding all elements inside the right containers but it doesn't show anything. It's a list with divs and images inside the <li> tags. Everything, except for the div that wraps everything, was dinamically generated. I've added width and height attributes, but still shows nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this. I had a error in the JavaScript when constructing the table.
Besides that, if I had "display:none" to a div that will be modified to "display:block" using JS after the click on a button, IE9 with IE7 standards doesn't allow me to show it.
I have to find another way but I think I'll modify the display of the div using JS after the document final load and all the divs are already in place.

Thanks for the comments nevertheless.